Looker - Average Headcount Measure in LookML
I'm new to Looker and trying to figure out how to create an Average Headcount measure. I've been able to do it in a Derived Table, but is it possible to do directly in an existing view? 
Below are two ways I've tried directly in my existing view, but I always get an error that aggregations of aggregations are not allowed or measures cannot be referenced in another measure. 
measure: daily_headcount {
    type: count_distinct
    sql: ${TABLE}.employee_id  ;;
  }

measure: average_headcount {
    type: average
    sql: COUNT(DISTINCT ${TABLE}.employee_id) ;;
  }

measure: average_headcount_2 {
    type: average
    sql: ${daily_headcount} ;;
  }

 Additionally, we'd like both a daily headcount average that could be achieved with the above (if it didn't error), AND a simple average - where we would sum Starting Headcount and Ending Headcount and divide by 2. Started on the below, but am stuck on how to dynamically define start_of_period and end_of_period. We would want these to be based on the date range selected in an Explore. Report Date is the date that the report (including all active employees) was pulled.
measure: sop_headcount {
    type: count_distinct
    sql: CASE WHEN ${report_date} = (
      SELECT MIN(${report_date})
      FROM ${TABLE}
      WHERE ${report_date} BETWEEN {{ start_of_period }} AND {{ end_of_period }}
    ) THEN ${employee_id} ELSE NULL END ;;
    description: "Count of distinct employees at the start of the selected period."
  }

measure: eop_headcount {
    type: count_distinct
    sql: CASE WHEN ${report_date} = (
      SELECT MAX(${report_date})
      FROM ${TABLE}
      WHERE ${report_date} BETWEEN {{ start_of_period }} AND {{ end_of_period }}
    ) THEN ${employee_id} ELSE NULL END ;;
    description: "Count of distinct employees at the end of the selected period."
  }

Thanks in advance - any advice or links to documentation is much appreciated. 
Was able to get Average Headcount using a Derived Table, but it cannot be filtered by any other dimensions such as department, employee type, location, etc — it only ever gives the average headcount for the full company.

It seems like your pdt gives you what you want but you can just filter it on just any dimension. So i think you might want to look into binding filters https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/reference/param-view-explore-source#passing_filters_into_a_native_derived_table
